# REPLACE INTO SQL Syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL Syntax for REPLACE

```
  $query = "REPLACE INTO ".TBL_ACTIVE_ADMINS." VALUES (:username, :time, :userlevel)";
  $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':time' => $time, ':userlevel' => $userlevel));
```

This works fine but I would like to adapt it slightly so that there is a where clause in it to only allow :userlevel to be '9' I tried this using the REPLACE SELECT but i keep getting an error

```
  $query = "REPLACE INTO ".TBL_ACTIVE_ADMINS."(:username, :time, :userlevel) SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE userlevel = 9 SET username = :username and timestamp = :time and userlevel = :userlevel";
  $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':time' => $time, ':userlevel' => $userlevel));
```

Can anyone explain to me what I have done wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind; after a lot of variations changing the code around, I decided to look at it from a different point of view. I have now coded a function that cleans the SQL tables each time the page is refreshed, therefore giving me an accurate count of who is currently active on my site.

I used the below code, then before the count was called I cleaned the database tables

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO ".TBL_ACTIVE_ADMINS." VALUES (:username, :time, :userlevel)";
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':time' => $time, ':userlevel' => $userlevel));
```

so my end code would look like this

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO ".TBL_ACTIVE_ADMINS." VALUES (:username, :time, :userlevel)";
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':time' => $time, ':userlevel' => $userlevel));

$query = "DELETE FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_ADMINS." WHERE userlevel = 3";
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':userlevel' => $userlevel));

$this->calcNumActiveAdmins();
```